# Read data instead of Response from C# Web API

Tags: c#

Im writing a program to interface with an API that gathers a url from the output of the API call.
I dont know how to read the actual output of the response, which is the part that I need help with.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace API_test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MakeRequest();
            Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Subscription-Key", "abc123def456ghi789");

            var uri = "https://theurl-that-goes-here/variable?" + queryString;

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            string sn = "XYZABC";
            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"sn\" : \""+sn+"\"}");

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(response); 
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The status code from the API gives me a statuscode 200 so everything is okay connecting
The output I get for each of the WriteLines are as follows ( in order )

System.Net.Http.StreamContent

System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Byte[]]

How do I get the response to dump the actual data?

Comment: Use `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: Success! @AlexeyRumyantsev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use async method

```
 await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

or if you prefer just for testing or for special cases some ui-blocking old style
you can do

```
 response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result()
```

But not recommend

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`
to get the result of your Task.

Comment: It is a bad practice to use `Task.Result`. The best way to make this code cleaner is to make it all asyncronous starting from `Main` method, and avoid `async void`.